# Split String deppending on characters in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Given is the following string (one line):

`a_Type_of_Data 0.847481:611x569+446+1200,0.515323:597x762+448+1101,0.587354:597x558+488+1207`

I would like to split it like this [611, 559, 446 ,1200], [597, 762, 448, 1101], [597, 558, 488, 1207]
So basically to get the 4 numbers between each ":" and "," regardless of the characters between the numbers.

I already tried to split the string on "," but then I still have the problem of the number in front of ":". Or the all go together like using`string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d]", "");`

Is there a way to do it with regex?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Passing `","` to `split` seems like the correct approach to me.  Then apply the regex `"([\\d.]*\\d):(\\d+)x(\\d+)\\+(\\d+)\\+(\\d+)"` to each element of the array returned by split.

Comment: Invalid escape sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use this regex `\d+x\d+(?:\+\d+){2}` to match those numbers separated by `x` and `+` and then split those individual strings using `[x+]` which will give you another array of numbers.

Check this Java code,

```
String s = "a_Type_of_Data 0.847481:611x569+446+1200,0.515323:597x762+448+1101,0.587354:597x558+488+1207";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+x\\d+(?:\\+\\d+){2}");
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    String[] data = m.group().split("[x+]");
    list.add(Arrays.asList(data));
}
list.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Prints the output like you expected,

```
[611, 569, 446, 1200][597, 762, 448, 1101][597, 558, 488, 1207]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Matcher` and its .find() method :

```java
package so21090424;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternFinder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String input = "a_Type_of_Data 0.847481:611x569+446+1200,0.515323:597x762+448+1101,0.587354:597x558+488+1207";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(":([0-9]+)[x\\+]([0-9]+)[x\\+]([0-9]+)[x\\+]([0-9]+),?");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1) + "\t" + m.group(2) + "\t" + m.group(3) + "\t" + m.group(4));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "a_Type_of_Data 0.847481:611x569+446+1200,0.515323:597x762+448+1101,0.587354:597x558+488+1207";

List<List<String>> result = Arrays.stream(input.split(","))        // split input at ','
       .map(e->e.split(":")[1])                                    // split each part at ':' and keep the second part
       .map(e->Pattern.compile("[+x]").splitAsStream(e).collect(Collectors.toList()))    // split at '+' or 'x' & collect to list 
       .collect(Collectors.toList());                            // collect to list 
System.out.println(result);
```